# Rewriting URLs with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert urls like this `http://example.com/page.php?user=x&post=x` into 
`http://example.com/blogs/user/post`

This is the code I have so far, not sure if I'm missing something or have done something wrong as it haven't been successful so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]{1,11})/$ page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [L]
```

**EDIT:** After making some amendments, it returns now an error 404 error saying `page.php` is not found. I know for certain the file is there.

**2ND EDIT:** Resolved 404 issue.

The `post` parameter is optional as well.
`user` can will have a mix of A-z0-9 (no character limit)
`post` can only be 0-9 with and upto 11 characters in length

Comment: What's your question?  And, why not try it to see if it works?

Comment: @Brad Sorry, I made a mistake in the post. I have tested the current code, it does not work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  The match isn't working as you expect?  The data isn't being passed?

Comment: @Brad The server returns a 404 page not found.

Comment: You are demanding a trailing slash in your pattern, but there is none in the example URL you have shown. And `{11}` is not _up to_ 11 characters, it’s 11 _exactly_.

Comment: ... and what URL did you try?  And are you sure your `.htaccess` file is being loaded?

Comment: @Brad Mod_rewrite is enabled on the server, I have changed the default homepage and it works. I tried this `site.com/blogs/username/post` AND `site.com/blogs/username/post/`.. both return a 404

Comment: What's the actual URL you tried?  Obviously it's not `site.com/blogs/username/post` since your `post` part is supposed to be numeric.

Comment: @Brad an example URL I would have tried is `site.com/blogs/admin/1`

Comment: @CBroe You are correct, I have made relevant changes and it seems it is now picking up the requested URL

Comment: You're requiring 11 digits, and your example URL just has 1

Comment: Are you sure `post` only contains digits 1-9? What about zero? And your regex originally permitted `_` for `user`, but now it permits `-` instead, and your edit mentions neither of those characters...

Comment: @Fraxtil, Sorry that was a mistake in the description. No changes were made to the user regex.

Comment: So what doesn't work now that you fixed the 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/?([a-z0-9]*)?/?$ page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
```

The `?` indicates that the matching is optional. Therefore for `/?` the slash is optional.

And for the second section after the `^blogs/?`

```
 ([a-z0-9]*)?
```

If you remove the `?` and `*` from the above to become like this :

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/?([a-z0-9])/?$ page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
```

The `user` will no longer become optional and must be fully matched.
Example `http://blogs/John`;
If you put `+` in place of * like below:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/?([a-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
```

The `user` need to be matched with at least 1 character. For example : `http://blogs/J`

And if you put `*` asterisk like below:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/?([a-z0-9]*)/?$ page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
```

It can match to zero length. For example : `http://blogs/` . Almost like optional.

If the match failed you will get the `404 Not found error`

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: What do you mean by why? Care to elaborate ?

Comment: How does it work? Why is this better than the other solutions?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. But I don't think it's better than other solutions. It depends on what you want, but I use * so it can match to zero length.

Comment: Well, quite plainly, the system put your post into the automatic low-quailty queue because it's too short. And I agree that it's too short. Add more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [L]
```

This transforms `http://example.com/blogs/abc_123/67890` to `http://example.com/page.php?user=abc_123&post=67890`.

The most notable change is that you apparently can't have a leading `/` in the first component of the rule, but I also removed the `{11}` constraint on the post ID since it's unlikely that would have the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

This code provides the desired results...

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-z0-9]+)?/?$ page.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-z0-9]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ page.php?user=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
```

I also amended the post ID constraint as Fraxtil pointed out.